# Why put public before static function in PHP?

Tags: php, visibility, static-methods

```
<?php
class newProfileTabs_Listener
{
    public static function template_hook ($hookName, &$contents, array $hookParams, XenForo_Template_Abstract $template)
    {
        if ($hookName == 'member_view_tabs_heading')
        {
            $contents .= '<li><a href="{$requestPaths.requestUri}#ourTab">Our Tab</a></li>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Question:

I saw this above php file, `static` by default is `public`, right? so why put `public static function`, not `static function`, is there any reason behind?

Comment: Honestly, it's probably a holdover of convention from C++/Java, where (I believe) the "public" keyword would not be optional.  Of course, the keyword is optional in PHP5 for backwards compatibility with PHP4, which had no concept of visibility.

Comment: @FrankFarmer is right. Also this improves the readability of the code and with an good editor it isn't to much to type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `static` function can actually be defined as `protected` and `private` (consider some utility methods used by another, public static method), you're right, by default it's `public`.

In fact, non-static methods are `public` by default too. Quoting the [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> Class methods may be defined as `public`, `private`, or `protected`. Methods
>   declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as
>   **public**.

Why is that modifier specified here explicitly? Well, probably it was written by the PHP team that supports the Python's maxima: [explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). One of the most obvious advantages of such approach is uniformity of the code: for *every* method there's a modifier that's clearly seen.

That's why rules like this...

> Methods inside classes **MUST** always declare their visibility by
>   using one of the private, protected, or public visibility modifiers.

... are not incommon in many teams' and projects' coding conventions (this particular rule was a quote from [ZF2 coding standards](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Coding+Standards)).